# RecyclerView slow scrolling performance and lag/halt sometime while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview to show the items and the items size could be 0 - 500.

But its scrolling performance is very slow and sometime its lags/halt the view 1~2 seconds.
I want to have a smooth scrolling experience in the recyclerView.

Even though if i remove the image from my cardview layout which i am loading with Glide, it makes no difference on performance.

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutGames">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewGamesToday"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:scrollbarSize="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**My cardview Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="35dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageTeamLogo"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/transparent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewHomeTeam"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTeamNameListing"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewTeamLogo"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageTeamLogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewTeamLogo"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewHomeTeam"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:text="3-1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorScoreListing"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewStatus"
                android:layout_centerInParent="false"

                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:text="Not Started"
                android:textColor="@color/colorMatchStatus"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewScore" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewAwayTeamLogo"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textViewAwayTeam"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewMatchStatus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAwayTeam"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTeamNameListing"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageViewFav"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewAwayTeamLogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewFav"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/star" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#efefef"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**onBindViewHolder method from my Adapter calss**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final GamesToday games = gamesTodayList.get(position);
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {

            case gamesOnlyRows:
                final GamesTodayViewHolder gamesTodayViewHolder = (GamesTodayViewHolder) holder;
                Glide.with(mCtx)
                        .load(games.getHomeTeamLogo())
                        .apply(options)
                        .into(gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewHomeTeamLogo);
                Glide.with(mCtx)
                        .load(games.getAwayTeamLogo())
                        .apply(options)
                        .into(gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewAwayTeamLogo);

                gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewHomeTeam.setText(games.getHomeName());
                if (games.getHomeScore().equals("null")) {
                    gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewScore.setText(games.getDate());
                } else {
                    gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewScore.setText(games.getHomeScore() + " - " + games.getAwayScore());
                }

                gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewEmptyCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent);
                if (games.getStatus().equals("CLOSED")) {
                    gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewEmptyCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ft);
                }
                if (games.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")) {
                    gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewEmptyCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_icon);
                }

                switch (games.getStatus()) {
                    case "CLOSED":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Finished");
                        break;

                    case "FINISHED_CONFIRMED_1":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Finished");
                        break;

                    case "FINISHED_CONFIRMED_2":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Finished");
                        break;

                    case "NOT_STARTED":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Not Started");
                        break;
                    case "ACTIVE":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Active");
                        break;
                    case "CANCELLED":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Cancelled");
                        break;

                    case "POSTPONED_UNDECIDED":
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText("Postponed");
                        break;

                    default:
                        gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewMatchStatus.setText(games.getStatus());
                }

                gamesTodayViewHolder.textViewAwayTeam.setText(games.getAwayName());
                gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                if (checkFavoriteItem(games.getId())) {
                    gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
                }

                gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (checkFavoriteItem(games.getId())) {
                            gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(mCtx, games.getId());
                        } else {
                            gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
                            sharedPreference.addFavorite(mCtx, games.getId());
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;

            case NotGamesOnlyRows:
                final GamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder = (GamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder) holder;
                gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent);
                gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

                if (checkFavoriteLeagueItem(games.getLeagueId())) {
                    gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
                } else {
                    gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent);
                    gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                }
                gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (checkFavoriteLeagueItem(games.getLeagueId())) {
                            gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                            sharedPreference.removeFavoriteLeagues(mCtx, games.getLeagueId());
                        } else {
                            gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewFavLeague.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
                            sharedPreference.addFavoriteLeagues(mCtx, games.getLeagueId());
                        }
                    }
                });
                gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.textViewLeagueName.setText(games.getLeague());
                Glide.with(mCtx)
                        .load(games.getCountryId())
                        .into(gamesTodayWithLeagueViewHolder.imageViewCountryFlag);
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try once removing the constraint layout in child layout

Comment: @Redman i tried by removing the constraint layout and replacing it with Linear Layout although my layout get messed but now its scrolling smoothly.

How to fix it using constraint layout?
thanks

Comment: Constraint layout as recycler child item is having some performance issue , saw only few cases where it happens and don't know the reason why it happens. So i cant help you there . Just avoid using constraint layout as list/recycler child item

Answer (score 5):

> It will load image on demand worked for me

```
 @Override
 public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(URL)
         .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

Comment: Give that man a medal! and 
To get item at current position: `.load(dataList.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()).getImage())`

Answer (score 2):

Use these Workarounds for smooth scroll

```
a) recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
b) recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

c) In `onBindView()`
It will provide Memory management cache to reduce image loading time

```
Glide.with(mCtx).load(games.getAwayTeamLogo()).
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .apply(options)
                        .into(gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewAwayTeamLogo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ConstraintLayout`, use `LinearLayout` and/or `RelativeLayout`.

Try it and see the performance change.

Comment: Linear layout is the wrong solution to use inside a recycler view , linear layout executes views from child to parent so first it has to execute the child and then its parent , this is time taking and processing work. Please read the constraint layout documentation. It is recommended to use , but nesting of constraint layout is also not recommended

Comment: i already use LinearLayout stills same issue

Answer (score 0):

i think the logic in bindViewHolder is making it slower, because while scrolling the bindViewHolder is called for every item that is about to get displayed.

Also, you can merge the logic for

```
if (games.getStatus().equals("CLOSED")) {

   gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewEmptyCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ft);
            }
if (games.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE")) {
                gamesTodayViewHolder.imageViewEmptyCircle.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_icon);
            }
```

with the next switch case...

Also, dont set the click listeners in bindview, its not good...you can set in the for that holder class